# Geometry problem, with circle.

Tags: geometry

[image]
We have that $DS \parallel BA$ and $∠DOS+∠DTS=180°$ and $O$ is the centre of the circle. I should somehow prove that $AB=AC$. In case you'd tell me I didn't show any effort I want to tell you that I tried to make this drawing for 40 minutes. Thank you for any help you could provide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $AB=AC$, using properties of an isosceles triangle,
$$\angle ACB=\angle ABC$$so this will be the goal of our proof.

---

Some headstart for you:

We have
$$∠DOS+∠DTS=180^\circ$$
so
$$∠TDO+∠TSO=180^\circ\tag{1}$$

Since $DS\parallel BA$,
$$∠SDB+\underbrace{∠DBA}_{=\angle ABC}=180^\circ\tag{2}$$

We also have
$$∠ABC+∠ACB+∠BAC=180^\circ$$

Your turn :)

Comment: What I got was that if $∠DTS=α$, then $∠DOS=∠BOA=180°-α$, and since $BO=OA$, $∠OBA=∠OAB=\frac{α}{2}$ and $BCA=90°-\frac{α}{2}$, so all there's left to prove there is that $∠CBO=90°-α$. Though I haven't used that $DS \parallel BA$.

Comment: So since $AO=BO$ and $DS \parallel AB$, can we make a presupmtion that it must be an iscosceles trapezoid?  If so, then $∠SDO=∠DSO$ and $∠ABD=∠BAS=∠TDS=∠DST$, therefore $∠TDO=∠TSO$ and since we know that $∠TDO+∠TSO=180°$, we get that both of these are equal to 90°. Therefore, the proof that $∠CBO=90°−α$ comes easily out of the triangle $TSB$, am I right?

Comment: @tryingtobemathematician Yep you are! Good job!

Comment: Good to know :). Thank you very much!